Scalatest comparing two identical Datasets failing
I created a sample dataset which I later compare with the results of a function in the Main app.
The sample looks like this:
val expected_ds_t1 = Seq(
  driveAggMonthly(1, 1),
  driveAggMonthly(2, 2),
  driveAggMonthly(3, 1)
).toDS().as[driveAggMonthly]

Where the driveAggMonthly class looks like:
case class driveAggMonthly(Month: Int,
                            numberOfDrives: BigInt)

Now, when I run printSchema() on expected_ds_t1, it looks like :
root
 |-- Month: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- numberOfDrives: bigInt (nullable = true)

The dataset I am comparing with this one, is created as follows:
    val source_ds = Seq(
      Drive(48, 0, "abc", "def", "2017-01-01"),
      Drive(94, 0, "ghi", "hkl", "2017-02-01"),
      Drive(82, 0, "mno", "pqr", "2017-02-05"),
      Drive(21, 0, "stu", "vwx", "2017-03-01")
    ).toDS().as[Drive]

    val result_ds_t1: Dataset[driveAggMonthly] = nr_drives_by_month(source_ds: Dataset[Drive])

  def nr_drives_by_month(input_ds: Dataset[Drive]): Dataset[driveAggMonthly] = {
    input_ds
      .groupBy(month(to_date(col("date"))).as("Month"))
      .agg(count(col("driveId")).as[Long].as("numberOfDrives"))
      .as[driveAggMonthly]
  }

The resulting schema looks like:
root
 |-- Month: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- numberOfDrives: bigInt (nullable = true)

Now when I run the following assert:
assert(result_ds_t2 === expected_ds_t2)

I get the following error message:
[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint] did not equal [Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]
ScalaTestFailureLocation: assignment.MainTest$$anonfun$1 at (MainTest.scala:44)
Expected :[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]
Actual   :[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]
<Click to see difference>

Even though I know both the schema and the data are the same.

What's the issue you're facing later? bigint or decimal(38,0) is the same type. bigint is the scala type, decimal is more the "SQL" type in some way.

The issue I am facing is that when I run assert to compare the the expected data set to the actual one, the actual one uses bigint and the expected returns decimal so my test fails.

Show us that assertion code and the error you get so that we can help

[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint] did not equal [Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]
ScalaTestFailureLocation: assignment.MainTest$$anonfun$1 at (MainTest.scala:44)
Expected :[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]
Actual   :[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]

Could you edit your post showing a minimal reproducible example detailing the code you have to do the assertion?

updated in the main description
